# How to add multiple exists fields with OR operation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "field1"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like my query to be modified in a way that I could add another filter with existing field having 'OR' operation between them.

Any idea how to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with `should`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field1"
                }
            },
            {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field2"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but should also return records who doesnt have any of the fields (I read that 'should' returns zero or one. I must have field1 or field2. dont want responses without one of those fields

Comment: I tested it, this query works for me and only returns documents that have one or the other field defined. You could wrap the bool query inside another bool query which uses ```filter``` to be extra sure. The linked documentation states: "If this query is used in a filter context and it has should clauses then at least one should clause is required to match."

Comment: for some reason it returns only results that contains "field1". results with "field2" never returned

Comment: Q/A is a bit old, but in order to have at least one field with a value, `minimum_should_match` would be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Use `should` Bool Query if either `field1 OR field2` should exist from the resulting documents.

Example:

```
POST your_index/_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field1"
                }
            },
            {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field2"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Use `must` Bool Query if either `field1 AND field2`  `must` exist in the output documents.

Example:

```
POST your_index/_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field1"
                }
            },
            {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field2"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```